# Turn Based Game Java(Stratego)

Tags: java, swing

so i have `JXButton[][] array` (gridLayout) and each JXButton holds an icon, a piece,which player belongs to and has a `mouseListener`.

I am currently trying to make the Stratego Game(Two Players-I handle both).
I set up the icons,pieces and how a piece should move alright.

Now i wish to make it play by turn.

For example when is Player1 Turn i need all Players2' pieces to change icon to Hidden(hidden.png) and vice versa.
I have tried something like this.

`tmp1, tmp2` are Icon arrays

`pieceimgsB,R` hold the Hidden Icon

`allbuttons` is my `JXButton[][] array`

```
    public void makeHidden(int iD){

            if(iD==1){
                for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                    for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                        if(allbuttons[i][y].getPlayerID()==iD){
                            tmp1[i][y]=allbuttons[i][y].getIcon();
                            allbuttons[i][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon(pieceimgsB[12]));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            else if(iD==2){
                for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                    for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                        if(allbuttons[i][y].getPlayerID()==iD){
                            tmp2[i][y]=allbuttons[i][y].getIcon();
                            allbuttons[i][y].setIcon(new ImageIcon(pieceimgsR[12]));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
 public void restoreHidden(int iD){
        if(iD==1){
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                    if(allbuttons[i][y].getPlayerID()==iD){

                        allbuttons[i][y].setIcon(tmp1[i][y]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else if(iD==2){
            for (int i=0;i<8;i++){
                for(int y=0;y<10;y++){
                    if(allbuttons[i][y].getPlayerID()==iD){

                        allbuttons[i][y].setIcon(tmp2[i][y]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I my mind `makeHidden` Player2 pieces hidden when its Players1 turn.

And `restoreHidden` should change back the Icons when its Players2 turn.

If these two methods seem ok , where my problem lies is how to implement the turns.

I must say that (When i click on a JXButton and then click on another one, the
piece moves on the board as it should). I tried having a flag in my mouseListener that when one actually moves the turn changes, but i cant make it work by turns.
I have wrote this :

```
public void letsPlay(){
        switch (turn){
            case 1: 

                getsb().makeHidden(2);
                //getsb().restoreHidden(1);
                if(getsb().getPlayerMoved()==true){
                    setTurn(2);
                }
                break;
            case 2:

                getsb().makeHidden(1);
                //getsb().restoreHidden(2);
                if(getsb().getPlayerMoved()==true){

                    setTurn(1);
                    //;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
```

I need to know if these two methods seem ok according to what they should do and a little insight on how to get it to work by turns.

Should i have the `getPlayerMoved()` (which returns the flag in the mouseListener in a while outside the switch case)?

Maybe i am tired and i dont see it but any insight would be helpful.
If someone needs it i can provide my `mouseListener` Code too although its a bit messy.

Comment: So what exactly is your question/problem? Please read "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: The fact you know "*its a bit messy*" is a signal that, if possible, it would be a good idea to take a short break and come back to the problem with a fresh mind, ready to do it fully the best you can - before you make changes which just "get the job done, no matter how badly it accomplishes the task"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an XY problem, the main point is not to specialize your listener to manage such behavior (and other inherent behaviors) but how to design something that is modular and easily maintainable.

I'd suggest you to try to workaround your problem by thinking how you could design your game and UI structure. Let's make a simple example:

First of all you have a game piece which has a type and a player, so why don't you use a specific object type for this? Eg:

```
class PieceType {
  String name;
  String iconName;
}

class Player {
  String name;
}

class Piece {
  PieceType type;
  Player owner;

class BoardCell {
  Piece piece;
}
```

Then you surely need a `Board` class able to manage the game board, eg:

```
class Board {
  private BoardCell [][] pieces = new Piece[10][10];

  public BoardCell cellAtPiece(int x, int y) { return pieces[x][y]; }
  /* other functions */
}
```

Finally you should have a `Game` class which manages the whole thing, eg:

```
class Game {
  Board board;
  Player[] players = new Player[2];
  Player currentPlayer;

  Player getCurrentPlayer() { return currentPlayer; }
  /* other methods, eg turn advance, check for correct position, eat piece etc */
}
```

Now you reached a point in which you have the structure of the game, and you can think about the UI, which should rely on the `Game` instance without the need of additional inputs (and `Game` shouldn't even know about the UI). You could extend a `JXButton` and provide custom behavior, eg:

```
class BoardButton extends JXButton {
  final private Game game;
  final private BoardCell cell;

  public BoardButton(Game game, int x, int y) { 
    this.game = game;
    this.cell = game.cellAtPiece(x,y);
  }

  public void refreshIcon() {
    if (cell.piece == null) { setIcon(null); }
    else if (cell.piece.owner != game.getCurrentPlayer()) { setIcon(hidden); }
    else setIcon(cell.piece.type.icon);
  }

  /* other utilities, like checking if a piece can be moved from here for current player and such */
```

Mind, I didn't answer directly to your question, but I explained some tools which would allow it to be solved easily together with all problems that you could find in implementation.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt add this . I actually have made everything according to what you say. And the first part of the code is actually in my Board class.Which is my View in my MVC model.
The letsPlay() i am trying to implement it in a Controller class.
I admit i have some problems clarifying between the three .

Comment: Should i change my question to if its possible to handle turns according to the View(Board) changes?